# How to use athena in react js

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I am developing a react js web app and I want some value  by querying in athena. Is there any way so that we can use Aws Athena in react js?

Comment: Yes, use the AWS SDK to talk to Athena, submit a query, wait for it to finish, access the data in the result bucket.

Comment: can you provide me some reference

Comment: Not really https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Athena.html

Answer (score 2):

TO invoke Athena operations from a React app, you can use the AWS SDK for JavaScript. You can find an example here that  demonstrates how to query for information from Amazon Athena:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javascript/example_code/athena/index.js